# Restrict UIButton titleText frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom UIButton that has some text I am setting on it dynamically.

The problem:

If the text gets too large, it will cover up a white arrow that is on the button's image located on the far right here:

[image]

When that text gets too large, that white arrow is covered, **which I need to avoid**.

Example:

[image]

Current code:

```
[self.filterButton setTitle:@"All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.filterButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.filterButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
self.filterButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
[self.filterButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Some approaches I have tried:

- Setting the titleText frame to be %0.85 of the buttons frame.
- Current code
- Tried to code it to where the frame cuts off at a certain point (of the titleText)

Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `titleEdgeInsets` rather than the `contentEdgeInsets`?